# How to get pairs of consecutive value in a list?

Tags: java

I want to get pairs of consecutive values by looping through an array:

```
List values = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
ListIterator<String> it = values.listIterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
      String start = it.previous();
      String end = it.next();
}
```

How do I get:

```
A, B
B, C
```

Comment: Which your problem?

Comment: Do you want to get only first and second value or current and next value from every index except last one ?

Comment: I want to get 1st and 2nd as a pair. then 2nd and 3rd as another pair.

Comment: so you want a Sliding Window with a size of 2 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve that with a classic `for` loop like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> values = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
    /*
     * You obviously want to output 2 values per iteration,
     * that means you have to adjust the condition to iterate to the
     * second last index (because of accessing i + 1)
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size() - 1; i++) {
        System.out.println(values.get(i) + ", " + values.get(i + 1));
    }
}
```

There is no need for an iterator and I strongly recommend not using just `List` (raw type) but `List<String>` (specifying item type).

Answer (score 4):

Try this :)

```
List<String> values = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
ListIterator<String> it = values.listIterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    String start = it.next();
    if(it.hasNext()) {
        String end = it.next();
        it.previous();
        System.out.println(start + end);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can declare `end` and initialize it to `it.next()` inside the `if` block.

Answer (score 1):

How about simply storing the previous value in a local var:

```
List<String> values = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
Iterator<String> it = values.iterator();
if (it.hasNext()) {
    String start = it.next();
    for(String end = null; it.hasNext(); start = end) {
      end = it.next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 8 or bigger version you also can try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> values = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");

    IntStream.range(0, values.size() - 1)
        .forEach(i -> System.out.println(values.get(i) + ", " + values.get(i + 1)));

}
```

Here it is used Stream which will loop from `0` (inclusive) to `values.size() - 1` (exclusive) and after that it is used forEach which accept Consumer with one argument (in this case the looping integer) and after that just print the result. I know that it is almost the same as iterative loop but I want to show that it can be made also this way.

Good luck!